# QtCreator Deployment using cmake

Tags: deployment, ssh, cmake, executable, qt-creator

Currently I am shifting my project from qmake to cmake, and know that QtCreator provides  deployment over ssh support if the build system used in qmake (of course deployment variables need to be defined in qmake) ? question is if deployment if deployment can also be achieved using cmake projects ?

Second query is How good is Qt-Creator integrated with cmake based deployment? Can the same level of integration can be achieved in cmake based QtCreator projects ?

any hint will be welcomed, thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the deployment depends heavily on the build system. There is basically no extra support for cmake projects at this time. You can hack something together using a script though, but that is not really comfortable.

The good news is that we are currently looking into making the deployment more general. So maybe in 2.7 or 2.8 this will be possible (both should get released next year in 2013).